# Best oracle for random numbers?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, oracles, random

What is the best oracle for random numbers as chainlink VRF is not yet available on Solana?

Answer (score 4):

Switchboard has one

https://switchboard.xyz/randomness

Here's a basic walkthrough on how to use Switchboard VRF

https://github.com/switchboard-xyz/vrf-demo-walkthrough

Here's a demo of using Switchboard VRF for a coin flip game

https://github.com/switchboard-xyz/vrf-flip

https://vrf-demo.switchboard.xyz/

Answer (score 3):

ORAO VRF. SDK and example are on the [ORAO Solana VRF Github](https://github.com/orao-network/solana-vrf)